# Is it worthwhile to edit old titles?

Tags: discussion, titles

While looking at a question, I saw a list of other related questions that had several meaningless titles:

- How can I make this code more elegant
- Can I make this C# for-loop more efficient?
- How to refactor a verbose datatype?
- How can I improve this OOP design? Is it even valid?
- How can I make this C# code better so it more closely follows DDD principles? Am I using factory correctly?
- How to refactor C# class to meet SOLID priniciple

Should I edit these titles to make them explain what the code is actually doing? Is this something that is beneficial to this site?

Comment: You may want to also add a specific point about old questions that have no answers. That may make a difference. Good question.

Comment: Please, please do so.  I have given many downvotes to such posts and I would love the opportunity to finally take them back.

Comment: Apparently worth editing [new *old titles* too](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/5209/revisions)!!

Answer (score 15):

Yes, please help bring any post that you find up to standards, as if they were posted today. Old posts do resurface in unexpected ways — for example, as you have observed, they may be recommended as related posts — and their presence may set a bad example. By the [Broken Window Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory), any bad example will likely inspire more posts of lower quality.

Comment: Applying a refactoring mindset to CR? Sweet. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. That's what makes Code Review one of the best Stack Exchange sites. Our users care about quality. It's a self-selecting crowd.